# How to say "I knew that Kanji, but not that reading"

Tags: translation, kanji

A friend recently showed me her name in Kanji. It was 梶原｛かじわら｝。I'm trying to figure out how I would say that "I knew that Kanji (原), but not that reading (わら)". If I was shown the Kanji first I would have guessed either はら or ばら.

This is what I came up with:

> 漢字の「原」は知っているが読み方は「わら」だと知りませんでした。

Comment: I occasionally run into such a situation and am very interested in knowing what should I call it.

Comment: Your sentence is fine but it'd be more reasonable to include 「わら」だと in the scope highlighted by は. i.e …読み方が「わら」だとは…

Comment: I wonder if it's not being typed, but spoken out loud, how would one say the first 「原」without first knowing its reading? Explicitly pronouncing the entire typed sentence reveals: かんじの「？」はしっているがよみかたは「わら」だとしりませんでした。

Comment: ^ あ～確かに・・・「『はら』という漢字は知ってましたけど、『わら』とも読めると（いうの）は知りませんでした。」とか・・・

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your translation sounds very good already (I'm a native speaker). If I force myself to come up with a variation of it, I got:

「原」という漢字は知っていましたが、「わら」と読むとは知りませんでした。

The most significant difference here is the use of 「～しました」 for the first 「知る」; since you use 「～でした」 for the second 「知る」, it sounds more natural to use 「～します・しました」 form there. (Use of the past tense is just a matter of taste.)

**UPDATE**

Since I can't comment yet, I'm answering to the comments here;

@user4092 Yes, that's more correct; I missed it. Omitting 「は」 from 「だとは」 makes you sound more casual. But 「は」 here also gives another implication. See below.

@Flaw In that case, I usually say something like 「この/その漢字を『わら』と読むとは知りませんでした」.

Combining the two points, you can say:

「この/その/『原』という漢字を『わら』と読むとは知りませんでした」

Here, 「知っていましたが」 is now omitted. 「とは」 in 「読むとは知りませんでした」 implies that you know something about the kanji other than how to *read* it. In this case, how to *write* it or that you have *seen* it.